# How many sockets can a node.js handle with socket.io?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, socket.io

I am developing a node.js application using express & mongodb also I am using socket.io to be able to handle the realtime events.

what is the max number of listeners on an event:

```js
io.on('posts' , (data) => {
   io.emit('posts' , data);
})
```

I mean how many users can I emit to them.

also I many channels can I use like the posts channel?

can I use tens of thousands of channels that can emit data changes to thousands of users?

is this make sense or there is a better way.

thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can I use tens of thousands of channels that can emit data changes to thousands of users?

Yes. In principle.

In actual applications, at this scale, a good amount of thought, planning, architecturing and solid implementation has to go into a solution that would practically work.